# Why can't android.os.build.VERSION be resolved to a variable?

Tags: java, android, variables

I am getting the error: "android.os.Build.VERSION cannot be resolved to a variable" as an error attached to the line "int myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION;" in the code below:

```
    public void test4_validate_mainOverflowMenuAbout()  {
    int myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION;
    String myModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

    if(myVersion >= HONEYCOMB && myModel == "MY PHONE")
        TestUtils.invokeMenuItem(@+id/dashboard_menu_item_about)
        assertTrue(TestUtils.waitForTextOnThePageWithTimeout("My Text", True, 1000));
```

I THINK that my control structure is proper, but would appreciate a gander from more experienced eyes.

TIA for any and all assistance!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Build.VERSION is a static class... Use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Answer (score 4):

In my code, I'm doing it like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) { ... }
```